# How cookies work?

Tags: cookies

I wanted to know the interactions of a browser (i.e. Firefox ) and a website.

When I submit my user name and password to the login form, what happens?
I think that website sends me some cookies and authorizes me by checking those cookies.

Is there a standard structure for cookies?

#### Update:

Also, how I can see the cookies of specific URL sent to my browser if I want to use that cookie?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Understanding Cookies**

Cookies are given to a browser by the server. The browser reveals the cookies as applicable only to the domain that provided the cookie in the first place.

The data in the cookie allows the server to continue a conversation, so to speak. Without the cookie, the server considers the browser a first-time visitor.

Have a look at these to know about browser cookies

[Understanding Browser cookies](http://web.archive.org/web/20110415181139/http://www.stratigent.com/web-sight-newsletter/web-analytics-newsletter-archive/understanding-cookies/default.html)

[http://internet-security.suite101.com/article.cfm/understanding_computer_browser_cookies](http://web.archive.org/web/20100706204912/http://internet-security.suite101.com/article.cfm/understanding_computer_browser_cookies)

http://www.willmaster.com/library/cookies/understanding-cookies.php

https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-22_11-6063884.html

Comment: -1 Sorry,links are dead or not so informative IMHO. This seems a good source of information http://ask-leo.com/how_do_i_delete_cookies_and_just_what_are_cookies_anyway.html

Comment: This one is pretty good : https://runestone.academy/ns/books/published/webfundamentals/CGI/cookies.html

Answer (score 22):

## Explanation via Pictures

[image: A world with and without cookies - explained]

## Simple Explanation by Analogy (via a story)

Freddie works at the Government Taxation Office (IRS/HMRC/ATO/CBDT etc). He deals with millions of people who come to see him everyday. And he has a very poor memory.

### In a World Without Cookies:

One day a customer walks in to Freddie's customer care desk:

Customer 1: "Good morning Freddie, so did you change my address like I asked you to?"

Freddie: "I'm sorry. I don't remember who you are? Who are you?"

Customer 1: "Dude, I spoke to you last Monday regarding this issue! How could you forget!"

Unfortunately, the HTTP protocol is stateless. There is no way Freddie (the server) can identify different customers (clients) apart from each other. He doesn't remember. He has a very short memory. There is a solution though:

### The World WITH Coookies:

The customer walks in to see Freddie (his name is Brian), but this time, the customer gives Freddie his taxation office ID card:

Brian May: "Good morning Freddie, My name is Brian May...so did you change my address like I asked you to?"

Freddie: "ah yes...hmmm......Brian May, Queen, Lead Guitarist, We Will Rock you......very interesting, I have your records here on my back end system.........let me bring up the records pertaining to your address........YES: I did in fact change your address. BTW since you gave me your ID that's all I need, you don't need to tell me your name is Brian May. Just give me your ID and I will be able to see that on my system".

### Explanation of Analogy

You can think of a cookie as kinda like an ID card: if you identify yourself to the server, the server will remember who you are and will treat you accordingly:

- e.g. it will remember what you've already ordered in your cart so far.
- it will remember that you like reading your website in Tamil / Cantonese / Swahili etc.
- it can (basically) identify who you are.

In this particular case, it is the Government Taxation Office who issues out the ID cards.

***Granted the analogy is a little strained and very simplified*** but hopefully, it will help you understand and remember the underlying concept.

Comment: This is the best answer i read so far! Can't wait for the next one about localStorage (-:

Answer (score 11):

Usually the cookie contains a session id number. The id number is then connected to session data that is stored on the server. The usual process is then:

1. Send login form
2. Server checks username and password
3. If correct, the username is stored in a session file on the server, along with various other useful information about the user (if it's a site admin, moderator, userid and so on).
4. The server sends back a cookie containing an id number that identifies the session file
5. The browser sends the cookie with each request to that server, so the server can open the session file and read the saved data.

Usually the password is not sent more than once (at login in step 1).

Comment: You can have cookies without sessions. In fact, it's specifically called a 'session cookie'.

Answer (score 2):

It depends, because there are many scenarios and abilities of usage of cookies.

One of scenarios is:

1. User submits login form.
2. Website authorizes the user and set cookie visible in website domain with user name, password (i.e. MD5 hashed) and sometimes other information.
3. Cookie is sent with each request, which allows website to check if request is came from the authorized user.

For more details read [Wikipedia article about cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie).

Answer (score 0):

After logging , the request to server is sent. At server side, it checks the visitor's identification against an ID that identifies whether it is a new user or the older one. 
If it determines it a new visitor,it  then creates a cookie for it and sends it back in its response  to browser.   Cookie that is generated in response to Server has a name and unique identification is sent back to a user end.   AT the user end ,after every visit to the same URL, browser rechecks cookie list and if it has the cookie for the same url , it is sent to server which identifies cookie ID and server shows the related history for this user then .

Comment: I think , this forum is meant for sharing the right information. If it is already answered then it doesn't mean ban to all others. Sharing and explaining the question is a simple straight manner matters.

Comment: If the right answer is accepted then there should be close status as well and if there isn't anything like that then it doesn't make any sense at all to say so.

Comment: There's no ban, you're right, but users are expected to contribute useful answers. Questions are not closed because there is an allowance made that what was the "best" answer before may be superseded by better technologies or methodologies. Your answer quite literally adds nothing to the discussion, hence the downvote. If you haven't done so already, I suggest reading the FAQs: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: And who has the authority to check the value addition and to devote someone ?

Comment: "Value" is subjective, and someone else can upvote your answer if they chose to do so. As for "authority," users gain privileges by contributing answers that their peers find useful, reflected via upvotes. Again, if you haven't read the FAQ, do so. If you feel my down-vote is unwarranted, you can always appeal to the moderators by using the Contact link.

Comment: I believe there is a difference between irrelevancy and relevancy. If you have the right to devote , you are for sure use it . I just don't want to  play a tag of war and if would have such devoting option to myself then i will use it keeping my mind very clear about relevant and non relevant.      Sometimes things are mentioned in a way by many people but everyone has a different way of expression and it should be respected unless it is non relevant and as per the context otherwise it looks as if someone has a match box and just want to make a fire to see what happens if i use it otherwise.

Comment: 1. It is completely acceptable to answer an old question with an already accepted answer 2. It is completely acceptable to downvote someone for doing this if you believe their answer is worth a downvote 3. You cannot appeal votes to mods.  Mods have no power to remove votes, nor would we use it if we could.  4. All this effort is wasted.  Instead of arguing like this, take a break.  Get up and go outside.  Pet a puppy.  Whatever.

Answer (score 0):

**Cookies** are small **data packets** that the **Web Pages** load on to the **browser** for various purposes.

Every time you re-visit a URL, the browser sends back a tiny package of this information back to the server which detects that you've returned to the page.

- Cookies are the reasons that keeps you logged into sites so that you don't have to enter ID and password every time you visit the website.
- Webmasters can use these cookies for monitoring the activity of Internet users.
- Some sites use third-party cookie to track your Web habits for marketing purposes.

Answer (score -1):

I found some information at this site that was really helpful to me and figure it might be of use: [Webfundamentals - Cookies](https://runestone.academy/ns/books/published/webfundamentals/CGI/cookies.html). It goes through what a cookie is, how they work, and the headers that are used to send them.

It says in summary that, cookies are pieces of information that are sent in HTTP requests inside the 'Set-Cookie' header from the server to the client/browser, or in the 'cookie' header in the client/browser to the server.

HTTP is stateless, meaning that one request to another has no knowledge of the state of the page you are browsing. Cookies were made to help address this issue, allowing users be 'known' by the site for as long as the cookie is set to be stored. By default cookies are stored until the client is closed, unless specified otherwise.