# Storing cookies after the cookie limit of browser and will this affect the performance of website

Tags: performance, cookies

What happens when storing the cookie limit of browser gets full and after that also i am storing the cookies then will it affect the performance of the site or will it have any impact on the performance of browser...? If its affects then i want to know the reason.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find what you need by reading the links in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968722/how-cookies-work) question.

The upshot is that the browser decides what to do when it has exceeded the number of cookies it can store; typically, it will purge cookies based on cache policy, and age.

If you mean that your cookie exceeds the maximum size (set in the RFC to 4096 bytes), you may get an error message, but most browsers "swallow" the error and truncate the cookie. It's a really bad idea to have such big cookies - it almost certainly means you're handling session state in the wrong way.

If your application requires cookies to function, you must make sure it can handle the loss or corruption of cookies, typically by logging you out if the cookie disappears or is invalid.

There's no reason this should lead to performance (as in response time speed) problems.