# How does cross-origin AJAX request 'withCredentials' figure out which cookies to use?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I can't figure out how this AJAX request knows which cookie to use. It uses the right one, but how does it know which one is the right one, or where is it specified (implicitly)?

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://remote-host.de/api/v2/session',
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
  },
  statusCode: {
    401: function() {
      // do stuff
    },
    200: function() {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
});
```

The request looks like this when I inspect it with Chrome and it has the right cookie set (the one of the remote host I am trying to request the login state from):

```
Accept:*\/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:_foo-bar_session=WjRMdExSQ1F6UlczbER0Ui9sQU9NNllIRWo1NmpCSXo2REh6akZmM1czODZ0M29adGh4aWg3ZmdrYWdxSU5KRVptUi8ybDladmJMHJhZWKZ3A5NlJCOTdWeFpCRGJQdHVvMnlxb0VQeWlCMGRtNDkxNDF3QVdhcnVRenlsQXExa3RNEtwZ1RNMW9oaE5TV1hLbHdnPT0tLXhtYUo3YytHY2wxWTFxanlXVTJjdlE9PQ%3D%3D--b22797a9b004d0759a43f4d94686edf909610a06
Host:remote-host.de
Origin:http://localhost:3001
Referer:http://localhost:3001/de
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

The response:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:3001
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:ETag
Access-Control-Max-Age:86400
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 22 Mar 2017 10:18:15 GMT
Server:nginx
Set-Cookie:_foo-bar_session=SGhyWGtWTFVoc1AzUWlldmIxTjFGVXVCQU9YVkduSDFISWtLamwwT01heW5HN25saVNyYWJ1b2ZDZDI4RzNGT1BzYWZOOHNVK21DN0kxNmJRS1VDSTdwb1VVS2NtcTZ3Y1dRYUJSaTYxckpOdDZFZ2RpRlQzTHZPdDdTTjljenZzQ1hTUjlCN0RoZUlkcWlpNm5KK2VRPT0tLTkwUlNuM0Z6TDZ2TWJjZVVSUExpb0E9PQ%3D%3D--568e4688b6ff5e17faa32a3bab1a7cf01807a581; path=/; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN
X-Request-Id:b43ce1c4-2c80-4sd5-8333-0g93ae4df940f
X-Runtime:0.013627
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

But how does it know?

Comment: The headers you pasted into the question are the *response* headers, right? They’re not the request headers. So as far as cookies go, that just shows that the server is sending a `Set-Cookie` header for whatever domain that response is from. So when your browser sends another request back to that domain, it sends that same cookie for that domain back in the request

Comment: Ah true, sorry. Will correct that. But it is the same cookie in the request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I’m misunderstanding the question, the browser just sends back whatever cookies it has that match the domain the request is being made to, and that match any `path` in the cookie.

[How cookies work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968722/how-cookies-work/1968734#1968734) has more details, with links to articles explaining how browsers handle cookies.

Comment: Yes, that's it. The way I inspected the cookie, it never showed that the domain is saved with it. That was the missing link!