# Why do not I receive cookies if between calls are from the same domain?

Tags: servlets, cookies, https, header, request

I have a problem with cookies.

A cookie is generated in a portal "https://portal.domain.com", with these properties:

domain: ".domain.com"

Path: "/"

when the portal calls my application in a tomcat "https://web.domain.com/app/controller?param=1&param=2", it does not send the cookie.

In the servlet the request.getCookies() is null always.

And I have tried many ways but without success.
maybe there is a header that blocks cookies.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Cookie is a session control mechanism used by a browser and a server in order to keep track of the interaction between them.

This is how Cookies work. A cookie is ONLY available to the domain that created it in the first place. And since portal.domain.com is different domain than web.domain.com then the Cookie created from the one domain is not passed on to the other.

See [How cookies work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968722/how-cookies-work) for more information

Comment: Thanks for replying, but if the domain is the same you should share the cookie no? because if I run the application (url) in another tab, if I share the cookie.

Comment: www.portal.domain.com is not the same domain with www.web.domain.com. These are two different websites hosted under the same top level domain.