# How to set cookie for a day

Tags: javascript, setcookie

This is the code I'm using. Please help me to set cookie for a day! I want to show welcome page when a visitor come back after 24 hours.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- hide from old browsers
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure) {
document.cookie = name + "=" + escape(value) +
((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires.toGMTString() : "") +
((path) ? "; path=" + path : "") +
((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "") +
((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
}
function setsplash() {
setCookie("splash", "1", "", "/");
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1968722/how-cookies-work

Comment: The third argument to the function is the time you want the cookie to expire. So give it the time you want, not `""`.

Answer (score 1):

Your method `setCookie()` is defined as

```
function setCookie(name, value, expires, path, domain, secure)
```

The third parameter is the expiration time. But you're calling

```
setCookie("splash", "1", "", "/");
```

i.e. the `expires` parameter is `""`. If you want the cookie to expire after 24 hours, use something like this instead:

```
var expires = (new Date(Date.now() + 86400000)).toUTCString(); // 86400000 milliseconds is 24 hours
setCookie("splash", "1", expires, "/");
```