# Sync a JavaScript variable between pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have been looking for ages trying to find a way to access a variable in another .html file. For example:
File 1 (HTML)

```
<!--some code-->
<script>
var x; //this should equal the variable in the other file.
</script>
```

File 2 (HTML)

```
<!--some code-->
<script>
var y = 0;
</script>
```

How could I do it? (I can move file 2's code into a separate .js file.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: do all in a seperate JS file and load this js file in both of your html files

Comment: Just move the `2`'s code into a seperate js file and include it like this in `1` <script type="text/javascript" src="yourscript.js"></script>

Comment: @OzgurSar you [no longer need `type="text/javascript"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265202/do-you-need-text-javascript-specified-in-your-script-tags) on `script` tags, just FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have better luck storing the variable in localStorage.

Set the key in one page

```
localStorage.setItem('key', value);
```

Retrieve the value from another

```
localStorage.getItem('key')
```

The other way is to use [cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1968734/2822041).

Comment: set and get are not the right way to use localStorage. I get `localStorage.set is not a function`.

Comment: should be setItem and getItem.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use [**localStorage**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) which is supported in all modern browsers.

Note that `localStorage.setItem()` will do `.toString()` on *everything* that you attempt to store that isn't a string yet. It is best to use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()` for setting and retrieving everything. Doing so may not be needed for strings themselves but it doesn't hurt much to just do it always.

I often use helper functions to make working with it easier, like this:

```
function storeObject(key, x) {
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(x));
}

function retrieveObject(key) {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
}

storeObject("test", { a: 2, b: 3 } );

const obj = retrieveObject("test")
console.dir(obj.a); // prints 2
console.dir(obj.b); // prints 3
```

PS I did not create a Stack Snippet because snippets don't allow the use of localStorage.